# How can I write a secure AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax, security

I need to write an AJAX request that is secure, and cannot be accessed through the source code or by any other means. Seeing as AJAX requests are written in javaScript/jQuery which is client-side, the request can easily be viewed. Is there any way to make AJAX requests invisible to users and unhackable?

Is it somehow possible to write AJAX requests with a server-side language such as PHP? From what I know I understand that PHP is a sever-side language, and that you need to write AJAX requests with a client-side language; however is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make AJAX requests invisible to users

No. Users can always see what your JavaScript asks their browsers to do.

> and unhackable?

The same way as any other request. Use SSL where appropriate. Use Auth where appropriate. Keep data in appropriate places. Pass identification tokens instead of real data where appropriate.

> Is it somehow possible to write AJAX requests with a server-side language such as PHP?

No. Ajax is, by definition, a request triggered by client side JavaScript.

You might be able to achieve the effect you want by making an HTTP request from the server *instead* of using Ajax, but that depends on what effect you actually want.